# Using UIAccessibility to read HTML selection

Tags: ios, swift, voiceover, uiaccessibility, avspeechsynthesizer

I am trying to implement a feature that will use VoiceOver to read a selected piece of HTML displayed in a `WKWebView`.

My initial attempt flattened the html to text and then used `AVSpeechSynthesizer()` to read an `AVSpeechUtterance` instantiated with the text:

```
let synth = AVSpeechSynthesizer()
let utterance = AVSpeechUtterance(string: myFlattenedText)
if synth.isSpeaking {
    synth.stopSpeaking(at: .immediate)
}
synth.speak(utterance)
```

This works generally, but the experience that VoiceOver gives is superior.  For example, my HTML has accessibility-enabled [MathJax](https://www.mathjax.org).  VoiceOver does a nice job reading the contextual math equations while the strategy of flattening the html to text does not.

I experimented with creating a `NSAttributedString` with the html fragment as detailed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39285959/is-it-possible-to-make-html-to-speech-same-like-text-to-speech), but that doesn't do any better.

Is there a way to tap into the VoiceOver functionality, perhaps using `UIAccessibility` somehow, that will read the accessibility-enabled HTML in the same way that VoiceOver does?

Comment: I _strongly_ suspect that you will only get the experience you want by embedding a web view.

Comment: I am using a webview.  When the user selects content in the webview, I want to read the content to the user.  I could use either a js or a native solution here, if it makes a difference.  I couldn't get anywhere with a js solution, though.

Comment: I must have misunderstood. Why can't users navigate the web view using VoiceOver?

Comment: Using VoiceOver works well.  Our app also allows users to select something and read it via a menu command.  I'm not crazy about the feature, but I don't make those calls :)

Answer (score 0):

What you're seeing is WebKit's `MathJax` support paired with carefully considered `UIAccessibility` support. While the most recent documentation I found suggests that [these properties are not accessible to web developers](https://webkit.org/blog/3302/aria-and-accessibility-inspector/), as an iOS developer, you should be able to traverse the `UIAccessibility` element hierarchy to dump the `accessibilityLabel` and `accessibilityValue` of your `MathJax` content.

Edit: As @mattsven points out, the issue is that WKWebView content is rendered in a remote process and thus does not expose its accessibility elements to the containing app.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion and the link.  I thought I was on a path to a solution (making a temporary webview with the html from selection), but I can't seem to get any any accessibility properties from either this temporary webview or my original webview.  `accessibilityLabel`, `accessibilityValue`, and `accessibilityElements` are all nil.

Comment: @JonBrooks Have you recursed through `accessibilityChildren`?

Comment: I only see a `accessibilityChildren` property in NSAccessibility not UIAccessibility.  Is it a property on something other than the view?

Comment: @JonBrooks Whoops. I meant to suggest trying [`accessibilityElements`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/objectivec/nsobject/1615147-accessibilityelements), which it appears you did. Let me experiment, some.

Comment: Update for the curious: `WKWebView` renders via a remote process, and [does not expose](https://github.com/kif-framework/KIF/issues/460) its accessibility elements in a way that can be accessed via your code.